# Conditional Probability and Combinatorial Analysis

Tags: probability

At the Philadelphia Zoo, there are 2 types of animals at the Water is Life exhibit: giant otter, red panda. The animals each perform one of these 5 actions: eating, sleeping, rolling, swimming, resting. I saw two animals at the exhibit and one of them was a red panda swimming.
Assuming that it is equally likely for me to have seen any combination of species and actions (including duplicates), what is the probability that both animals were swimming?

My thoughts are that the other animal is still equally likely to perform one of these 5 actions(independent of the swimming red panda I see), so the probability that both animals were swimming should be 1/5. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

In unconditional case you have 100 cases, Corresponding to seeing either a panda or an otter , And each of them could be doing any 5 things.

When you condition upon the fact that you saw a panda swimming, The sample space now has 19 elements, Out of which there are three in which both are swimming hence the probability is 3/19.